# iOS: Find cell.tag value after user reorders cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView that can have upto 7 cells. I have set the option `cell.showsReorderControl = YES;` and the user is able to reorder cells.  While creating cells, I have also included cell.tag.

After the user reorders the cells, I would like to know arrangement of the cells in the table.  To accomplish this, I thought I'd set the tags (not sure if this is the right approach).

So my questions is in prepareForSegue, after the reshuffle of cells by the user, I would like to know what the tag value is for each cell?

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",proposedDestinationIndexPath.row]];
    [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:proposedDestinationIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sourceIndexPath.row]];

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

To verify I did NSLog

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"Number of Objects in Array %i", arrayTag.count);

    for (NSString *obj in arrayTag){
        NSLog(@"From ArrayTag obj: %@", obj);
    }   
}
```

Log WITHOUT moving cells:

```
2013-07-10 17:50:47.291 MyApp[1634:c07] Number of Objects in Array 7
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 0
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 1
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 2
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 3
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
```

Log AFTER moving/shuffling cells:

```
2013-07-10 17:51:55.329 MyApp[1634:c07] Number of Objects in Array 7
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, what have you tried to get that?

Comment: I haven't tried anything.  I'm not sure how to get the tag value of each cell after the user reshuffles the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Actually add one `NSMutableArray` in `.h` file.

Now in `viewDidLoad` method `intialize` it

```
arrayTag = [NSMutableArray array];
```

While `adding cell's tag` add it in `array`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

   .........
   .........
   .........

   cell.tag = indexPath.row;
   NSString *strCellTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.tag];
   if(![arrayTag containsObject:strCellTag])
   {
      [arrayTag addObject:strCellTag];
   }
   return cell;
 }
```

Now in these `delegate` method `replace` tag

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
   [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",proposedDestinationIndexPath.row];
   [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:proposedDestinationIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sourceIndexPath.row];
}
```

**EDIT** : You have order of cells with its tag .........

Comment: Thank you Prince.  This looks great.  I'll try this in a few hours and mark it as correct if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the Code above.  Log AFTER moving/shuffling cells, I'm not getting unique values.  If you look at the log above, you'll notice that when I don't move any cells around, it shows the cells in order with unique values.  However, after shuffle/moving cells, there are multiply cells with the same values?  Thanks.